# Format created datetime string to 00:00:00 in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in javascript and I have trouble formatting my string given the following inputs:

```
let input1 = '03 D. 07 H. 10 M.'; // output = '03:07:10'
let input2 = '05 H. 00 M.'; // output = '05:00'
```

I tried to split it and check if it contains `D`, `H` or `M`. Any ideas what I can do?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a really awful format to work with. Is there nothing you can do to improve it?

Comment: What have you done that has not worked? Can you explain by providing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a regular expression with `split` or a regular expression with `.replace`.

```
[^\d]+
```

Means replace any combination of characters that are not digits (`[0-9]`)

This will leave a trailing ":" which you can remove with another replace or using something like `.slice` on the split.

```js
var input1 = '03 D. 07 H. 10 M.'; 
var input2 = '05 H. 00 M.'; 

console.log(input1.replace(/[^\d]+/g, ":").replace(/:$/, ""))
console.log(input1.split(/[^\d]+/).join(":").replace(/:$/, ""))

console.log(input2.replace(/[^\d]+/g, ":").replace(/:$/, ""))
console.log(input2.split(/[^\d]+/).join(":").replace(/:$/, ""))
```